# Undefined subroutine error in perl package

Tags: perl

This is main file upload.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use lib '.';
use XFSConfig;
use XUpload ; 
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use Fcntl ':flock';
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTML::Form;
use Encode;
        sub xmessage
    {
       my ($msg) = @_;
       &lmsg($msg);
       $msg=~s/'/\\'/g;
       $msg=~s/<br>/\\n/g;
       print"Content-type: text/html\n\n";
       print"<HTML><HEAD><Script>alert('$msg');</Script></HEAD><BODY><b>$msg</b></BODY></HTML>";
       exit;
    }

    sub lmsg
    {
       my $msg = shift;
       open(F,">$c->{htdocs_tmp_dir}/$sid.html");
       print F qq[new Object({"state":"error", "msg":"$msg"})];
       close F;
       &logit($msg);
    }
```

and this function calls a function

```
 &XUpload::ProcessFile()
```

and XUpload::ProcessFile() function calls a function &xmessage("Fatal"); which is defined in upload.cgi

and now i get this error

```
Undefined subroutine &XUpload::xmessage called at Modules/XUpload.pm line 17.
```

It seems package XUpload   is unable to find function xmessage defined in upload.cgi at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xmessage` sub in your cgi script is defined in the `main` package, while the `XUpload` module is (apparently) operating in the `XUpload` namespace.

Resolving this issue will ultimately involve learning about Perl's namespaces and the `Exporter` module. But a quick and dirty fix is to create an alias for your sub in the `XUpload` package. Add this line to your main script:

```
*XUpload::xmessage = *message;
```

Comment: Dirty fix indeed. That's crazy awful X_X